# Suggestion to change my Laptop RAM DDR3

Tags: laptop, memory, sony-vaio, ddr3

My Vaio **VPCEA1BGN** has Memory Type: **DDR3** 
[**2GB**] **PC3-10600** DDR3
[**1GB**] **PC3-8500**, DDR3 (**non-ECC**).
There is no extra free slot now. I am planning to change one ram to **4GB**. 
which one RAM i should remove now. I am still confused over the ECC types. Any suggestion while i am buying the ram?. I am looking into Corsair or Transcend.

Maximum It can hold 8GB [2*4GB]
The Crucial scan tool gave the Report as: http://www.crucial.com/systemscanner/viewscanbyid.aspx?id=28AC5F1531D926C3
I am using Win7 Professional 64Bit.

Comment: Sorry, no shopping suggestions on SuperUser.  But I will say this: ignore ECC.  It is almost only used in servers and workstations. 99+ % of the laptops will use non-ECC SoDIMMs

Comment: I suggest you put in the same size in all slots.  This means your best chance for compatability is two of the same product which are the same size.

Comment: @Ramhound: Ya i am hoping for it.. But nw i am going to change it for the first slot later the second one..!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Hennes is correct.  Use non-ECC RAM in your laptop.

@Ramhound is partially correct.  Compatibility is not an issue in 95% of scenarios.  You can have RAM of different sizes with no problems.  The primary reason you should use two sticks of RAM from the same vendor of the same size and speed are for dual channel performance benefits.  Vendors usually sell dual channel kits, which are nothing more than two sticks of the same size and speed RAM which are from the same production run.

Also, please note that even this may not be necessary, depending on your motherboard's memory controller.  Intel has a mode called Flex Mode on certain chipsets which can utilize dual channel with different size memory sticks.

Ultimately, you need to look into your motherboard's chipset to see what types of memory configurations it supports--dual channel, flex mode, etc.

If you don't care about the benefits of dual channel configurations, then the speed and size of the new stick does not matter.  The motherboard will use the LOWER of the two speeds, however.

Comment: My Motherboard is intel H55 Whats your suggestion i would love to get all the benefit from the laptop. Processor is i5-520m 2.40Ghz with turbo boost upto 2.93Ghz.. Nowadays i am feeling irritated over the system.. It blows a very hot air..! Unable to sustain with it.. I felt because of the RAM. I am not using large applications..!

Comment: Re "Flex Mode on certain chipsets", I suspect it depends on CPU AND NOT on chipset. Reason: sample CPU spec  (https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/53438/intel-core-i32350m-processor-3m-cache-2-30-ghz.html) lists Flex Memory support ("yes") and the spec  for a chipset (https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/52808/mobile-intel-hm65-express-chipset.html) often used with it does NOT mention Flex Memory. If it depended on the chipset I'd think it'd be listed there. Though I do suspect support can depend on particular mobo or BIOS. Can anyone cite authoritative answer?